# How can a function that only occurs after another has finished impact how the first function works?

Tags: python, class

Using python's turtle module to create a snake game and I'm running into some issues. Here's the code for the game loop and movement, followed by the relevant out_of_bounds and self_collision methods. The goal is to display "YOU DIED" and then to end the game loop. This works for the out_of_bounds test, but not the self_collision test, and I can't figure out why. Gameloop is in a different class than move, out_of_bounds, and self_collision.

```
def gameloop(self):
    self.player.move(self.target)
    if self.player.out_of_bounds() or self.player.self_collision():
        print(f'{self.player.segments[-1].pos()}')
        return
    else:
        turtle.ontimer(self.gameloop, 200)

def move(self, other):
    self.x += self.vx
    self.y += self.vy
    if self.self_collision() or self.out_of_bounds():
        turtle.color('red')
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setpos(105, 255)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.write('YOU DIED', font=('Garamond', 60))
    if self.segments[-1].pos() == other.body[0].pos():
        self.grow()
        other.move()
    else:
        for seg in self.segments[:-1]:
            seg_index = self.segments.index(seg)
            self.segments[seg_index].setpos(self.segments[seg_index+1].pos())
        self.segments[-1].setpos(self.x, self.y)

def out_of_bounds(self):
    if self.x == -15 or self.x == 615 or self.y == -15 or self.y == 615:
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0
        return True

def self_collision(self):
    head = self.segments[-1]
    for seg in self.segments[:-1]:
        if seg.pos() == head.pos():
            return True
```

There's other code, but I don't think it's relevant to the question. I have the snake stored as a list of turtle objects (that's the referenced self.segments). When out_of_bounds is true, the "YOU DIED" is displayed and the game loop ends, in that order. When self_collision is true, the game ends without "YOU DIED" being displayed. If I remove the gameloop test, the test within move works just fine. The gameloop test prints out the position of the collision, but the test within move is not executed. I have not been able to find anything about this happening, though I'd be surprised if this is unique. I genuinely don't know how the gameloop test, which can only execute after the move test has finished, is doing anything before the move test is finished.

Comment: I suspect what is happening is when you call move() both the out of bounds and collision tests return False. The move function then grows the worm (you don't show the grow code) and when the gameloop checks again, the collision is now True so the game exits without the "You Died" text being printed.

Comment: This was exactly right. Just moved my checks to the end of move and it started working, thank you.

Comment: One other thing that could cause surprising results is that you have the tests in a different order between the move() and gameloop() functions. For an 'or' condition if the 1st condition is True then the 2nd condition won't be evaluated. This could be why you don't see one of your test functions executed in some cases.